# Rails Javascript - Calling a javascript function from the view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript file abc.js. I have kept it inside app/assets/javascripts/abc folder.

In my application.js file, I have given

```
//= require abc/abc
```

In my view, I need to display the object that is returned by a function inside the `abc.js` file.

I am calling the function by the following command

```
%h4.sub-header Test Project

%textarea.form-control{rows: 10}

  :javascript

    abc.diff(@a, @b)
```

I am getting the a & b values from the controller.

But the function is not being called. Instead the sentence "abc.diff(a,b)" is being displayed.

Could anyone tell me how to call the function inside my view?

Comment: Can you update your post to include your view code?

Comment: I have updated my view code now.

Comment: You'll need to interpolate to evaluate @a and @b in Ruby before passing to `js` (`abc.diff(#{@a}, #{@b})`).

Comment: My view file name is index.html.haml. Yes , I am using haml.
I tried it with #{}. Now it s displaying like this....
abc.diff('...(JSON object1)....', '....(JSON object2)....')

Comment: I think this should work as long as you use interpolation and the line in question is indented two spaces more than `:javascript`.

Comment: Hmm it is indented 2 spaces more than :javascript. But it is still not working. Thanks anyway

Comment: Also, I think you should include the subfolder in your asset manifest with something like `//= require_tree ./abc` where `abc` is the name of the subfolder.  Also not sure why that same `abc` string is prefixed in your call in the view.

Comment: I have to say I am a little curious about what function abc looks like.  I'm trying to imagine an application where it wouldn't be more appropriate to either implement server side or using UJS so that concerns are properly separated.

Comment: Ya, just now I took off the prefix abc in my view. Now I am just doing diff(#{@a}, #{@b}). I also added the //=require_tree ./abc in my application.js file. Still same thing is happening.

Comment: Is other Javascript from your manifest file getting included?  If so, can you search for this Javascript function using Firebug or something to make sure it is getting included properly?  You could try placing `abc.js` directly in your javascript folder to see if that works (shouldn't need to include explicitly).

Comment: I tried that as well. My abc.js file consists of the following code.

function diff(a,b){
....logic....;
return object;
}

Comment: Did you confirm the Javascript file is getting loaded and you don't get console errors when the code is invoked?

Comment: Yes, I did not get any console errors when the code is invoked.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't use `diff` in case it is a reserved function or something but that seems like a long shot.  At this point, I would replace your call in the view with an `alert` to make sure you are set up right to call JS there.

Comment: One more idea - use the `javascript` tag - change :javascript to `= javascript_tag do`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside haml javascript blocks you can just do string interpolation. Also indentation is very important in haml (obviously). So your view should look like:

```
%h4.sub-header Test Project
%textarea.form-control{rows: 10}

:javascript
  abc.diff(#{@a}, #{@b});
```

Without more info it is hard to say more, but in general this is not the preferred way: your code should be precompiled in javascript assets, and generally I define variable or add `data` attributes to specific items.

So either something like

```
:javascript
  var a = #{@a};
  var b = #{@b};
```

ad inside `abs.js.coffee` write

```
$ -> 
   abc.diff(a,b)
```

The cleanest solution imho is something like:

```
%body{'data-a': @a, 'data-b': @b}
```

and inside `abs.js.coffee` write

```
$ -> 
  a = $('body').data('a')
  b = $('body'_.data('b')
  abs.diff(a,b)
```

Of course, this depends whether it applies to your solution, my apologies for digressing :)